# What happens in case of the PayPal checkout interruption on the client side?

Tags: javascript, paypal

So I've checked https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/ and I see that the buttons perform everything on the client side using JavaScript (for example capturing an order).

Let's take the sample integration code as an example:

```js
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Display payment options on your web page
```

I noticed that PayPal automatically closes the PayPal checkout window if the page where the JavaScript code exists was closed - but is this enough?

What if a computer crash, internet timeout, or any similar accident happens on the client side for example **just** before the execution of `actions.order.capture()`, will the order be ever captured later?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make everything clear, I am going to answer my own question.

I actually didn't understand what do the words **authorize** and **capture** mean here.

**Authorize** means the payer confirmed that they want to pay. The funds aren't withdrawn from the payer's account after an authorization yet until a capture happens.

**Capture** asks PayPal to withdraw the funds from the payer's account.

So if capture didn't happen, there won't be a problem since the payer will still have their money.